# Default sorting order of getResultList() hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, sorting, jpa

What is the sorting mechanism of Hibernate for implementation of getResultList() of JPA ? Is it by the id or is it not guaranteed a proper order ? I did not see any detail regarding this in JPA javadoc.

```
/**
     * Execute a SELECT query and return the query results
     * as an untyped List.
     *
     * @return a list of the results
     *
     * @throws IllegalStateException if called for a Java
     * Persistence query language UPDATE or DELETE statement
     * @throws QueryTimeoutException if the query execution exceeds
     * the query timeout value set and only the statement is
     * rolled back
     * @throws TransactionRequiredException if a lock mode has
     * been set and there is no transaction
     * @throws PessimisticLockException if pessimistic locking
     * fails and the transaction is rolled back
     * @throws LockTimeoutException if pessimistic locking
     * fails and only the statement is rolled back
     * @throws PersistenceException if the query execution exceeds
     * the query timeout value set and the transaction
     * is rolled back
     */
    List getResultList();
```

But each time I run and test the results it give me the list ordered by id. That is what I am still confused although a genius had down voted this problem

I just put show_sql true and checked the generated sql. It does not have any sorting included.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's is the order of the elements returned by the database.

You will never know which order it is as the database is free to return a `ResultSet` in any order (especially when inserting and deleting in a table).

To ensure a certain order you have to define this yourself.

Comment: Yes I also feel you are correct .But when I tested I always get these results sorted by id :O

Comment: @SanjayaLiyanage You have probably inserted all data with ascending id. Then it is natural for a new table to return it in this order but as I said you cannot count on this.

Comment: So is it the order we inserted  data as Chase also thinks? Sorry I ask these things to make sure the answer

Comment: @SanjayaLiyanage When never deleted then it is (in most cases) the order of the data inserted. When you delete data it is possible that at the place of the deleted data new data will be inserted. So you will never now and no dataase makes any provisions about the order.

Comment: So it depends on how the particular DB (MySQL, Oracle ,Derby) provides the data back if I am not mistaken

Comment: @SanjayaLiyanage Yes, this highly depends on the database used.

Answer (score 4):

Method `getResultList` from `javax.persistence.Query` returns the default order which returned by DB. However, you can specify the order in query

```
    List customerList = em.createQuery("SELECT r FROM Customer r").getResultList();
    List customerList1 = em.createQuery("SELECT r FROM Customer r order by r.lastUpdatedDate").getResultList();
    List customerList2 = em.createQuery("SELECT r FROM Customer r order by r.lastUpdatedDate desc").getResultList();
```