# Does JPA getResultList necessarily return an ordered list?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence

When using a simple JPQL query the includes an "order by" clause, with Hibernate, the result seems to be always an ordered List, specifically an ArrayList. As far as I can see the JPA specification (JSR 220) just says

> public List getResultList(); Returns: a list of the results.

What do other implementations of JPA do? I mean do they return some kind of an ordered list? If not, and if implementation independent code is desired, I guess the result should be sorted before use.

It is not a duplicate of [Default sorting order of getResultList() hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17607755/default-sorting-order-of-getresultlist-hibernate) which asks about the guaranteed order of the query with Hibernate, and was answered that one should specify "order by". I had asked about JPQL in general and where was this specified.

Comment: It returns a List ... which by definition has an order. Whether the user has specified an ORDER BY is up to them but a returned List always has an order.

Comment: I mean an order corresponding to the "order by".

Comment: if the user specified the ORDER BY then it is in that order. If the user didnt set the ORDER BY then it is in the order returned by the RDBMS. Just the same with an SQL SELECT statement ... you can specify ORDER BY and get a specific order, or get the "natural" order

Comment: It does behave as you say, but the specification does not oblige JPA to behave in this way. Or does it?

Comment: @JonathanRosenne The comment by Neil is perfectly correct: "It returns a List ... which by definition has an order" meaning a list *always* has an order. However, this might be implicit or unspecified (and up to the implementor, here: Hibernate) or specified by the developer that defines the `ORDER BY` explicitly. The JPA Spec does not tell implementing providers which kind of implicit order they have to choose in case no `ORDER BY` is given by a programmer. This is perfectly fine, as otherwise it would be a bad Spec.

Comment: Somehow, the problem has previously been discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17607755/default-sorting-order-of-getresultlist-hibernate?rq=1

Comment: It seems I didn't make myself clear. I have a query with "order by". I get back a list. So far so good. What guarantee do I have that foreach on the list will return the items in the specified order? I do know that with Hibernate it does, but this behavior does not seem to be specified by JPA.

Comment: So you have an "ORDER BY", so it orders results in that order (since that is your specified order). So you inspect the List returned and they are in that order. That is what ORDER BY is for, and will be followed by all compliant JPA providers, because otherwise order by has little sense. No idea what you mean other than that